# Why does Gmail server try to authenticate me for sending a message to a mailbox on their server?

Tags: email, authentication, networking, smtp

I want to send an email to a mailbox on Gmail's servers. But I cannot understand why Google wants to authenticate me, the sender.

I want to act as the sending mail server. So using openssl, I open a TCP connection to smpt.gmail.com. Openssl takes care of the TLS handshake, and I am ready to send a message of the SMTP protocol

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -star
ttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000005)
.. Lots of TLS or SSL details ...
---
250 SMTPUTF8
```

I send the HELO message:

```
HELO smtp.gmail.com
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service
```

And I try to send a message:

```
MAIL FROM: <me@nowhere.com>
530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at ...
```

But Gmail servers responds that I need to be authenticated.

I would understand authenticating with the mail server if I were reading from a mailbox, but I don't get why I need to authenticate to send a message to a mailbox.
I can't find much documentation on the internet regarding this either.
Is there some kind of mechanism where every owner of a mailserver on the planet needs to create a google account just to send emails to a gmail mailbox?
How does the mail servers at Microsoft outlook send messages to Gmail servers?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Google wants to make sure you are who you say and not a spammer.

Answer (score 0):

Modern SMTP splits *message submission* into a separate transaction, distinct from *message transport.* You are generally required to authenticate with your local MTA (Gmail's if you are sending *from* Gmail, Outlook if that's where you are sending from, etc) to submit a message, and then the transport network of SMTP proper takes it from there.

There used to be a time when you were able to submit a message to a remote MTA by something called direct injection, but spammers abused this (along with pretty much every other feature of email) to the point where this model was no longer sustainable.

The modern message submission protocol runs on port 587, and generally requires authentication, and thus can obviously only accept submissions from local users for whom the server has identity and authentication information.

The transport protocol, by contrast, runs on the original port number, 25, which is more or less universally firewalled now for residential IP addresses. (Inside an organization, you might still be able to connect to a local mail server on port 25 and perhaps even submit messages without authenticating.)

In addition, regular mail servers on the modern Internet need to maintain a positive reputation. This helps keep the bad apples somewhat isolated, but raises the bar for newcomers and minor independent operators. See e.g. SenderBase for one such reputation system, though the big operators typically have their own proprietary ones which are not available to outsiders.

Comment: @Zephers: By connecting on port 587, you use "SMTP for Submission", which requires authentication. You probably wanted to use "SMTP for Relay", which uses port 25.

Comment: Except if your IP address is not set up as a mail server, port 25 will typically be blocked for similar reasons, and if not, you still have the reputation issue.

Comment: First of all: I liked your answer, I just wanted to relate it to question. Now to your comment: Yes, port 25 is usually blocked for outgoing connections by hosting providers, but I never had issues connecting to incoming mail servers on port 25 from residential Internet connections. And yes, your message will not get delivered by any reasonable mail server, but this is beside the point. Zephers asked questions such as "How does the mail servers at Microsoft outlook send messages to Gmail servers?", to which the answer is "by using SMTP for relay on port 25".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated slightly to highlight the difference between the port numbers.